# Python 2.7, populating tables with arrays

Tags: python, arrays, populate, packets

I need to populate different rows of a table with the correct field, I am currently populating one column using an array, the results of which are gathered by parsing a file (network capture containing packet details).

self.payloads[] is one array for payload data.

self.frames[] is another for frame data.

to populate one column, I currently use:

```
i=0
for data in self.payloads:
                self.ui.tableWidgetData.insertRow(i)
                self.ui.tableWidgetData.setItem(i, 5, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data))
                i+=1
```

How would I use 5 arrays to populate a table?

Comment: What does this have to do with packets? Just attaching random tags to a question is not going to get you more answers, it's going to get you downvotes from people who are experts in an area that's irrelevant to your question and not experts in what you're actually asking about.

Comment: Meanwhile, it's not very clear from your question, but I think what you may be looking for is [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). That will let you iterate over all 5 arrays in the same loop.

Comment: Sorry, thought i'd mentioned what I was parsing

Comment: And do you think that's relevant to your problem? Is someone who knows everything about network packets but nothing about Python, Qt, etc. going to be useful in solving your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
i=0
for payload, frame, otherthing in zip(self.payloads, self.frames, self.otherthings):
    self.ui.tableWidgetData.insertRow(i)
        self.ui.tableWidgetData.setItem(i, 3, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(frame))
        self.ui.tableWidgetData.setItem(i, 5, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(payload))
        self.ui.tableWidgetData.setItem(i, 6, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(other thing))
        i+=1
```

`zip` takes a bunch of separate iterables (like your lists) and zips them together into a single iterable, where each element is a value from each input. This is how you iterate over a bunch of separate iterables in lock-step. For example:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4, 5]
>>> for i, j in zip(a, b):
...     print i, j
0 3
1 4
2 5
```

---

As a side note, you don't need to maintain a counter manually like you're doing with `i`. See the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
>>> for index, i in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']):
...     print index, i
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` is one option.

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]

b = [0, 1, 2, 3]

for i,j in map(None,a,b):
    print i,j
```

Comment: While you can (ab)use `map` for this, you really should use `zip` when what you want to do is zip together multiple iterables. It's not actually documented that `map` can take `None` as a function.

Comment: @abarnert - the docs do describe None as a function argument for map and the resultant affect.

Comment: @wwii: I was sure that was removed from the docs in 2.7, but… I guess not, only in 3.3.

Comment: @abarnert - using ```None``` as the function argument to ```map``` in v3.3 throws ```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable```.  Probably why it was removed from the docs.

Comment: @wwii: Yeah, I remembered completely wrong. I thought the plan was to quasi-deprecate it in 2.6 and remove any mention from the docs in 2.7, while breaking support in 3.x. But I guess they decided that, coming together with two more radical changes (from list to iterator and from zip_longest behavior to zip_shortest behavior), there was no reason to make the dropping-None thing gradual; it's unchanged from 2.5 to 2.6 and 2.7, and gone completely in 3.0. Sorry for the confusion.